# jQuery drop down auto-suggest divs - to disappear after user clicks outside of an input field which calls that divs?

Tags: php, jquery, autosuggest

I have a search input field on my web - absolutely similar to the one on facebook. When you type any character into an input field, jQuery creates auto-suggested drop-down divs according to that character(s). Works great.

But I have a problem - if that input area is not empty, the div dropdown list generated by jQuery stays open all the time, unless you delete all characters from that input field.

So my question is very simple - how can I make, when you click outside that div drop-down list (or input field I guess) - for that drop down list simply to disappear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be helpfull if we could see some code, but you could probably achieve this using the [.blur](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) or the [.focusout](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/) methods.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input').blur(function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: That removed input field (not divs driven by that field in my case) but its a heck great code. And I know where Ill use this trick thanx Lips!

Comment: No problem...The answer could easily be refactored to hide the div-drop-down. Let me know if you need help with that.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
$(document).click(function (event){
    if( $(event.target).parents('.dropdown-div-class,.input-class').length==0 ){
        $('.dropdown-div-class').hide();
    }
});
```

`dropdown-div-class` is the class of div that you need to hide, `input-class` is the class of your input field. You may change selector to fit your needs. But, in most of cases, all such scripts are include this functionality as well. Check if you have some errors or something else that prevents div from being hidden.

Comment: I used Mike's solution is quite suitable now, ill check back later on this since I need more time to reprogram current behavior of jquery to the elements..

Answer (score 0):

You can bind click event on you body and check if the clicked element is the dropdown div or the input or child of the dropdown div. If neither one them is true then you should hide the dropdown div.